# Which of the encryption approaches should I use?

Tags: encryption, rsa, aes

I need a system to exchange very secret data (source code that is a trade secret). I will use Crypto++ so practically I can use all encryption algorithms, although I really prefer to use an industry standard.

Currently I'm thinking on these methods:

1. Have the server generate 2048/4096-bit RSA keys, send the public key over to the client, have the client encrypt the data then send it over to the server.
2. Use a key exchange method like Diffie-Hellman (Diffie-Hellman-Merkle to be correct) to exchange an AES-256 key.
3. Initiate a TLS connection and tell the server the AES key directly.

Which approach do you believe I should use? I'm not concerned about performance as long as it's reasonable; security is what matters. If none of them, please suggest another method.

P.S.: I might use chaining on the symmetric algorithm, like AES-Twofish-Serpent.

EDIT: Any recommended software must be in a license that won't restrict proprietary usage. LGPL is as restrictive as it must get. That rules out GPL.

Comment: I'd simply use GPG. It is ready to use and some kind of industry standard for emails (for those who care about secure emails). But you might have some special requirements, I don't know.

Comment: AES-128 is actually more secure than the other AES variants. http://neworder.box.sk/newsread.php?newsid=22916

Comment: GPG really isn't useful in this case.

@AES-128 being more secure, AES is hardly close to being broken. The page you linked even says the attacks are completely unpractical. It also says only the 9 round of Rinjdael has potentially been broken. The AES standard specifies the minimum is 10 rounds and AFAIK the 256-bit version has 14 rounds.

Comment: To add more to GPG, it's under GPLv3, which I can't use at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using an existing S/MIME (or CMS) implementation with a solid cryptographic module to encrypt your content.

S/MIME enveloped data makes a nice format for storage of encrypted data "at rest": the envelope records information about the algorithms and keys used so that the information will be available to authorized recipients later, when it is needed.

Also, even if it doesn't support the "best" algorithms (like ECDH key agreement), a good library is much less likely to have vulnerabilities than something written by a general programmer. Since it is far, *far* more likely that security will be breached by an implementation error than cryptanalysis, it makes sense to minimize those errors.

---

In legitimate protocols, public keys are signed by one of a small number of trusted issuers, whose public keys are distributed by some secure means "out-of-band". If you already have a secure means to get a public key to the message sender, why bother sending another? And if you don't, you're screwed.

TLS and S/MIME depend on having a set of well known CA certificates at every client. These are used to sign the server's public key so that a client can detect attempts to substitute keys. The protocol can't bootstrap itself; there must be a secure way to distribute "trust anchors" out-of-band.

Also note that RSA is incredibly slow compared to symmetric ciphers. Real protocols generate a *"content encryption key"* for a symmetric algorithm like AES, then use an RSA public key as a *"key encryption key"* to encrypt the content encryption key for the message recipient(s).

---

So, the main problem is getting your public key to the client securely. If you can do that, either option #1 or #2 is good—assuming that you just use that public key, rather than trying to send another one "in-band". In fact, in [CMS](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2630.html), Option #1 is called "key transport", and Option #2 is called "key agreement".

In practice, the "server" could use a certificate issued by a CA that is already well known, or the client can compare a hash of the certificate with one that you tell him over the phone, or carve into the face of a cliff, or whatever. The critical thing is, *all* of your security depends on the integrity of the certificate. You have to protect it from tampering.

While Crypto++ is an "industry standard", its security depends on *how you use it.* [Just like Jerry told Kramer,](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Seinfeld#The_Robbery_.5B1.3.5D) "the door must be… *closed!*" Using the cryptographic primitives in Crypto++ with in a poorly designed protocol will get you nowhere. That's why I'm stressing the use of CMS (a higher-level protocol) together with a good cryptographic module (cryptographic primitives).

Comment: Crypto++ looks like an industry standard, at least to me. The algorithm most likely won't change, and even if it will, all the stored files will have meta-data accompanying them, so a changing algorithm isn't an issue.

Comment: Which is why I am asking here, to be sure I actually use it correctly.

Answer (score 11):

Don't develop your own key exchange and/or key provisioning protocol(s). This is what historically breaks most products and, unless you are a cryoptographer (not a programmer with crypto experience), you'll likely get it wrong.

Use off-the-shelf protocols like SSL/TLS. Eg. TLS initialized with RSA keypairs for mutual authentication and AES session keys sounds appropiate for what you describe

**Updated**

[Bruce Schneier](http://www.schneier.com/book-sandl-pref.html):

> "A colleague once told me that the world was full of bad security
>   systems designed by people who read
>   Applied Cryptography"

erickson in his post has already give you plenty of evidence why designing your own key provisioning and management protocol is flawed. I just want to drive the point home why Mallory is alive and doing quite well, thanks to overconfident developers:

You design the scheme you propose where the client encrypts with a public key and sends the document back to you. Things work great, but 1 year down the road the certificate is approaching expiration. You send an email out to your clients with the new certificate containing the public key you want your users to sign encrypts the documents with for you. Unknown to you is that over the past 4 months your ISP admin has received a bribe to route all your IP traffic through a remote machine. Your email is intercepted before distribution and your attached certificate is replaced with another one. All your clients are now sending their ultra secret documents encryted for someone else's private key. An application decrypts each one, stores it, then encrypts it with your public key and forwards the traffic to you. You won't even know is happening, untill by accident during a visit to a client's site you notice that the certificate he uses is not the one you distributed.

You mention in your post as an option to chain algorithms. Nobody is going to brute force you. Your weakness will be key management, and the attack will take some form of social engineering to fool someone is using the wrong key, or reveling the private key (again, bribes go a long way). Industry agreed protocols have steps to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks, they may rely on PKI infrastructure that recognizes designated key use and trusted authorities, they add certificate revocation list check steps to the validation etc etc. Just 'I encrypt with public key, you decrypt with private' does not make a secret safe.

Comment: Actually, even *if* you are a cryptographer, you'll likely get it wrong. That's why cryptographic algorithms and protocols are usually developed by groups, in the open and rigorously reviewed publicly for years, before they are deployed.

Comment: I guess I'll bundle OpenSSL and just use TLS to connect in that case. However, if I encrypt my data using a public key I receive from the server why would I need to use TLS? The data encrypted with the public key can only be decrypted with the private key, which doesn't leave the server.

Comment: @Wikie: In theory you're right (omitting all public key provisioning issues like root of trust and handling revocation etc etc). In practice nobody encrypts data using an RSA key. You encrypt it using a session key and you encrypt the session key using an RSA key. If is a channel encryption (coupled, online, synchronous), a protocol like TLS does the key management for you (derivation and exchange of the session key). If is a document encryption (decoupled, offline, asynchronous), there are protocols like S/MIME or PGP that solve this.

Comment: Why should I encrypt the master key using the RSA key? That sounds pointless IMO.

It's document encryption AFAIK.

Comment: Where are you going to store the symmetric key associated with the document? Are you going to use one single key for all your documents? How are you going to handle a key renewal, re-encrypt all documents existing?

Comment: @Remus: The symmetric key will be stored in a centralized storage server which only be connected to the central server. The only way to get the key would be to steal the HDD and try to break the AES XTS encryption.

Comment: The ISP can't possibly intercept it, since the key will be embedded directly in the application executable, and it will verify itself against the server for modification. Isn't it possible to have a certificate without an expiration date or a really long expiration date?

Answer (score 0):

What about ssh ? (rsync on ssh for example) ?

Comment: SSH is kind of a pain on Windows, and I need more than just upload the files. I might not even upload them, just tell the server the encryption key/get it from the server.